# Two set of right brackets over multiple lines

Tags: equations

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts, setspace}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{rcases}
            \begin{split}
                \left.
                \begin{alignedat}{4}
                    n^2 &> 0\\
                    n &> 0\\
                    1 &> 0\\
                \end{alignedat}
                \right\}
                &\Rightarrow n^2 + n + 1 > 0
                \\
                \left.
                \begin{alignedat}{4}
                    n       &> 0\\
                    n + 2   &> 0\\
                    1 - n^2 &< 0\\
                \end{alignedat}
                \right\}
                &\Rightarrow n(n + 2)(1 - n^2) < 0
            \end{split}
        \end{rcases}
        \Rightarrow
        \frac{n^2 + n + 1}{n(n + 2)(1 - n^2)} < 0
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Which results in this:

[image: equation]

However, I want the bracket in the right to only extend over the actual 2 lines, not the whole equation. How can I achieve this? Also, I've mixed 2 ways of creating right brackets, so if you know a cleaner way, help will be appreciated

Comment: Which actual two line? Those with the implication signs?

Comment: I guessed a preamble but get `Package amsmath Warning: Cannot use \`split' here; (amsmath)                trying to recover with \`aligned' on input line 27.` which makes me suspect you are using different definitions?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I updated the packages

Comment: @Bernard those that resulted from the first set of equations, i.e. n^2 + n + 1 > 0 and n(n + 2)(1 - n^2) < 0

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry. updated

Comment: Thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shrink the outer delimiters and restore settings for the inner one I just chose the amount of shrinkage by eye here

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\xdef\restoredels{%
  \delimitershortfall=\the\delimitershortfall
  \delimiterfactor=\the\delimiterfactor
}
\delimitershortfall=30pt
\delimiterfactor=500
            \left.
\restoredels
        \begin{aligned}
            \left.
            \begin{alignedat}{4}
                n^2 &> 0\\
                n &> 0\\
                1 &> 0\\
            \end{alignedat}
            \right\}
            &\Rightarrow n^2 + n + 1 > 0
            \\[\jot]
            \left.
            \begin{alignedat}{4}
                n       &> 0\\
                n + 2   &> 0\\
                1 - n^2 &< 0\\
            \end{alignedat}
            \right\}
            &\Rightarrow n(n + 2)(1 - n^2) < 0
        \end{aligned}
    \right\}
    \Rightarrow 
    \frac{n^2 + n + 1}{n(n + 2)(1 - n^2)} < 0
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is there any way to do this so that it will work for any height? i.e. not a fixed delimiter

Comment: @Toma there's always a way but not particularly easy (and not at this time of night:-) but such things often require adjustment anyway so it's not clear if a much more complicated solution would be worth it, someone may take up the challenge though.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

More complicated ... with use `tikzmark` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,
                tikzmark}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
\begin{rcases}
    \begin{split}
  n^2 & > 0\\
    n & > 0\\
    1 & > 0\\
    \end{split}
\end{rcases} & \Rightarrow n^2 + n + 1 > \tikzmarknode{A}{0}    \\
\begin{rcases}
    \begin{split}
n       &   > 0\\
n + 2   &   > 0\\
1 - n^2 &   < 0\\
    \end{split}
\end{rcases} & \Rightarrow n(n + 2)(1 - n^2) < \tikzmarknode{B}{0}
%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,
BC/.style = {decorate,  % Brace Calligraphic
             decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm,
                         raise=2mm},
             very thick, pen colour={black}
            },
                        ]
\draw[BC]  (A.north -| B.east) --
    node[right=4mm] {$\Rightarrow \frac{n^2 + n + 1}{n(n + 2)(1 - n^2)} < 0$}
              (B.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

After two compilation the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another  solution, with an `array` environment and `\bigdelim`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array, bigdelim, multirow} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{\jot}
\begin{array}{r@{}l@{}l@{}l@{}l}
    n^2 > 0 & \rdelim\}{3}{*}\\
        n > 0 & & \Rightarrow n^2 + n + 1 > 0 &\rdelim\}{4.5}{*} \\
        1 > 0 & & & & \multirow{2.5}{*}{$ \Rightarrow\dfrac{n^2 + n + 1}{n(n + 2)(1 - n^2)} < 0 $}\\
\addlinespace
        n > 0 & \rdelim\}{3}{*} \\
        n + 2 > 0 & & \Rightarrow n(n + 2)(1 - n^2) < 0\\
        1 - n^2 < 0 \\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

\end{document} [image]